It becomes array when sending Django nested dict to API
I sent the dict data with this in Python:
    data = {
        "test":{
            "A":"Adata",
            "B":"Bdata",
            "C":"Cdata"
        }
    }       
   
    response = self.client.post("/api_patch/",data,follow=True)

then receive this as:
@api_view(["POST","GET"])
def api_patch(request): 
   
   print("request.data",request.data)
   print("request.data type",type(request.data))

However this shows,
request.data <QueryDict: {'test': ['A', 'B', 'C']}>
request.data type <class 'django.http.request.QueryDict'>

Somehow A B C is treated as array.
Where am I wrong?

You're sending the data as form-encoded data, not JSON. (You can verify that by printing request.headers in your view.)
Hard to tell what self.client is from your code, but in case it's a Django test client, set content_type to a JSON-esque content type:

If you provide content_type as "application/json", the data is serialized using json.dumps() if it’s a dict, list, or tuple.

response = self.client.post(
    "/api_patch/",
    data,
    follow=True,
    content_type="application/json",
)

